# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jet'

Tags: python, django, pip, jet

im trying to run a project at https://github.com/VladKha/MovieNet

but i keep getting the error even after `pip install jet` multiple times

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()

File "C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception()

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception  raise _exception[1]

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init*_.py", line 398, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django_*init*_.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

File "C:\Users\rajan\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 228, in create
import_module(entry)

File "C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load

File "", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed

File "", line 1050, in _gcd_import

File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load

File "", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jet'

Comment: Did you install the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: yes but i get error installing psycopg2==2.7.3.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same problem. For met the following pip install did the trick: `pip install django-jet`.